# Return rows matching one condition and if there aren't any then another in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following table  as an example:

```
numbers    type
--------------
1          1
5          2
6          1
8          2
9          3
14         2 
3          1
```

From this table I would like to select the closest number that is less or equal to 5 AND of type 1 and if there is no such row matching, then (and only then) I would like to return the first closest number larger than 5 of type 2

I can solve this by running two queries:

```
SELECT number FROM numbers WHERE number <= 5 AND type = 1 ORDER BY number LIMIT 1
```

and if above query returns 0 results, I simply run the second query:

```
SELECT number FROM numbers WHERE number > 5 AND type = 2 ORDER BY number LIMIT 1
```

But is it possible, to achieve the same result by only using one query?

I was thinking something like

```
SELECT number FROM numbers WHERE (number <= 5 AND type = 1) OR (number > 5 AND type = 2) ORDER BY number LIMIT 1
```

But that would only work, if mysql first checks the first conditional in the parentheses against all rows and if it finds a match, it returns it, and if not, then it checks all rows against the second parenthesed conditional. It will not work, if it checks each row against both parentheses and only then moves to the next row, which is how I suspect it works.

Comment: Your first query needs to have `ORDER BY number DESC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will do what you want. It selects all numbers that match your two query constraints, and orders the results first by `type` (so that if there is a result for type 1 it will appear first) and then by either `-number` or `number` dependent on `type` (so that numbers <= 5 sort in descending order but numbers > 5 sort in ascending order):

```
SELECT number 
FROM numbers
WHERE ( number <= 5 AND type = 1 )
   OR ( number > 5 AND type = 2 )
ORDER BY type, CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN -number ELSE number END
LIMIT 1
```

Output:

```
3
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fbewsz3TW6pQiCN6MKKoVk/0)

Answer (score 0):

Combine the two, and you always prefer type 1 over type 2, hence the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`. The `ABS` means whichever is first by type, is the closes to the number 5.

```
SELECT number, type
FROM numbers
WHERE (number <=5 AND type=1) OR
      (number > 5 AND type=2)
ORDER BY type ASC, ABS(number-5) ASC
LIMIT 1
```